# System.AccessViolationException in Word on Comment.DeleteRecursively

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto

I am trying to delete comments from a Word 2010 document. I added them myself, wherever I identified a font that does not conform to company standards.

But whenever I call DeleteRecursively, I get a System.AccessViolationException. Deleting comments using VBA runs without any errors. The object methods differ, since in VBA I have Comments(i).Delete instead of deleteRecursively.

I have a product version of 14.0.7015.1000.

```
 foreach (Word.Paragraph para in storyRange.Paragraphs)
        {
            if (Helper.ParagraphHasWrongFont(para))
            {
                Word.Range anchor = para.Range;
                if (anchor.Comments.Count == 0)
                {
                    Word.Comment comment = anchor.Comments.Add(anchor, "The font is wrong in this one.");
                    comment.Author = "System";

                }
            }
        }

  for (int i = ActiveDocument.Comments.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (ActiveDocument.Comments[i].Author == "System")
            {

                Word.Comment cmt = ActiveDocument.Comments[i];

                cmt.DeleteRecursively();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was misleading. I was using references to Office 2010, but the method DeleteRecursively() is a newer feature of Office 2013.

I replaced the call with comment.Delete(), which is available in the older versions of Office.

[MSDN forum link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31b38122-de51-4416-a4be-877e64207884/systemaccessviolationexception-in-word-on-commentdeleterecursively?forum=worddev)